# Can We use jquery onscroll function in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, vue.js, vue-component

i want to use JQuery on scroll function to stick my navbar at the top in vue.js how can i do so.

this is what i am doing my **Components** that is navbar in bootstrap which i want to stick onscroll. also let me know any better approach or solution plese give me

'''

```
<template>
<div>
  <b-navbar class="navbars" toggleable="lg" type="dark" variant="info" v-on:scroll="scrollFunction">
      <router-link to="/"><b-navbar-brand href="/">Home</b-navbar-brand></router-link>
    <b-navbar-toggle target="nav-collapse"></b-navbar-toggle>

    <b-collapse id="nav-collapse" is-nav>
      <b-navbar-nav>
       <router-link to="/contact"><b-nav-item href="/contact">contact</b-nav-item></router-link>
        <b-nav-item href="#" disabled>Disabled</b-nav-item>
      </b-navbar-nav>

      <!-- Right aligned nav items -->
      <b-navbar-nav class="ml-auto">
        <b-nav-form>
          <b-form-input size="sm" class="mr-sm-2" placeholder="Search"></b-form-input>
          <b-button size="sm" class="my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</b-button>
        </b-nav-form>

        <b-nav-item-dropdown text="Lang" right>
          <b-dropdown-item href="#">EN</b-dropdown-item>
          <b-dropdown-item href="#">ES</b-dropdown-item>
          <b-dropdown-item href="#">RU</b-dropdown-item>
          <b-dropdown-item href="#">FA</b-dropdown-item>
        </b-nav-item-dropdown>

        <b-nav-item-dropdown right>
          <!-- Using 'button-content' slot -->
          <template v-slot:button-content>
            <em>User</em>
          </template>
          <b-dropdown-item href="#">Profile</b-dropdown-item>
          <b-dropdown-item href="#">Sign Out</b-dropdown-item>
        </b-nav-item-dropdown>
      </b-navbar-nav>
    </b-collapse>
  </b-navbar>
</div>
</template>
```

'''

**My Script of this component is not working for me anyone can help me**
'

```
<script>
import $ from 'jquery'
export default {
  name: 'AppNav',
  
  created () {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.scrollFunction);
  },
  destroyed () {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.scrollFunction);
  },
  methods: {
    scrollFunction (event) {
      // Any code to be executed when the window is scrolled
       $(window).on('scroll', () => {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 20) { // Set position from top to add class
          $('.navbars').addClass('header-appear');
        }
        else {
          $('.navbars').removeClass('header-appear');
        }
      });
    }
  }

}
</script>
```

'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can achieve the desired effect *without jQuery*. Basically, you need a condition on an element's class (see `:class=...`), based on a scroll event (see `@scroll=...`). Does this example help?

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '.scroll-demo',
  data: {
    scrollStatus:false,
    scrollTriggerY:50
  },
  created:function(){
    window.addEventListener("scroll", this.scrollManager);
  },
  methods:{
    scrollManager:function(){
      var scrollY = this.$refs["scrollParent"].scrollTop;
      this.scrollStatus = scrollY > this.scrollTriggerY;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
div {
  border:1px solid #333;
}
.scroll-demo {
  position:relative;
  height:200px;
  overflow:auto;
}
.main-content {
  height:1000px;
}
.nav-bar {
  height:30px;
  background-color:grey;
}
.header-appear {
  background-color:red;
  position:sticky;
  top:0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<!-- just some demo app -->
<div class="scroll-demo" @scroll="scrollManager" ref="scrollParent">
  <div class="nav-bar" :class="{'header-appear': scrollStatus}">...navbar...</div>
  <div class="main-content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the structure of your document and exact behaviour you wish to achieve, probably it may be achieved only with [position: sticky](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) CSS property. It is not always possible and has some limitations, but worth to try.